# Reverse engineering some Javascript Chatroom code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to understand the code some guy wrote for a chatroom. There is one line that I just can't seem to wrap my head around. What is this line doing:

```
params['id'] = r.insertID;
```

The line of code is at the end of the following code snippet:

```
    $('#submitForm').submit(function(){

        var text = $('#chatText').val();

        if(text.length == 0){
            return false;
        }

        if(working) return false;
        working = true;

        // Assigning a temporary ID to the chat:
        var tempID = 't'+Math.round(Math.random()*1000000),
            params = {
                id          : tempID,
                author      : chat.data.name,
                gravatar    : chat.data.gravatar,
                text        : text.replace(/</g,'&lt;').replace(/>/g,'&gt;')
            };

        // Using our addChatLine method to add the chat
        // to the screen immediately, without waiting for
        // the AJAX request to complete:

        chat.addChatLine($.extend({},params));

        // Using our tzPOST wrapper method to send the chat
        // via a POST AJAX request:

        $.tzPOST('submitChat',$(this).serialize(),function(r){
            working = false;

            $('#chatText').val('');
            $('div.chat-'+tempID).remove();//this is removing the temporary line :)

            params['id'] = r.insertID;
            chat.addChatLine($.extend({},params));
        });

        return false;
    });
```

**MY CURRENT UNDERSTANDING:**

The previous code is run after the html page is loaded. The code schedules an event handler for when a user submits a forum with id `submitForm`. So far so good. From there, a few verifications are done, and eventually the code gets to actually calling the function that will output the new line of text inside the chatroom `chat.addChatLine($.extend({},params));`.

The `params['id']` value would later be used in the function `chat.addChatLine` to identify each `<div>....</div>` that is being placed into the chat.

**QUESTION:** Where is the value coming from? There is no global variable `r` outside of the javascript function. From the looks of it, the value would appear to be `null`. Am I missing something here?

ORIGINAL SOURCE OF THE CODE:
http://tutorialzine.com/2010/10/ajax-web-chat-css-jquery/

Comment: In my understanding, he is calling a post api where he is inserting something in database which returns row_id. Now `r` is the response of this post call. You can refer [jQuery-Post](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) for more reference.

Comment: So, I'm finished my answer. I hope you can now fully understand the workflow of this code. In short again: `r.insertID` is the row id of the database for this single entry. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`r` is the ajax response object, given to the callback function by `tzPOST`. This `tzPOST` is just a wrapper for [`$.post`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/). So `r` is the ajax response by the requested webserver. Some shorter version of the code for better example:

```
//                                                   | here is 'r'
//                                                   | as parameter of the callback
//                                                   |
$.tzPOST('submitChat', $(this).serialize(), function(r) {
    params['id'] = r.insertID;
});
```

If you search for the `tzPOST` function in the `scripts.js` file, you will see, that it just uses jQuery's [`$.post`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) function. The developer uses this to have a shorthand and a central point for the requests URL:

```
$.tzPOST = function(action, data, callback) {
    $.post('php/ajax.php?action='+action, data, callback, 'json');
}
```

On the php/server side the response is set in `ajax.php` by the lines:

```
$response = Chat::submitChat($_POST['chatText']);
echo json_encode($response);
```

The `Chat::submitChat` function is found in the `Chat.class.php` file. It inserts everything into database and returns the row id of the database.

```
public static function submitChat($chatText){
    /* someother code here*/

    // save to database and get row id back
    $insertID = $chat->save()->insert_id;

    // return the insert id
    return array(
        'status' => 1,
        // this is later 'r.insertID'
        'insertID' => $insertID
    );
}
```

Now `params['id']` has the value of `r.insertID`, **witch is the databse row id of the inserted data**.

---

To understand where `r` comes from, we take a look at the `$.post` inside the `tzPOST` function. This is a alias for jQuery's `$.ajax` function. So instead of `$.post` we can use `$.ajax` too.

Then it should be more clear where `r` comes from.

```
// this is exactly the same as the one line used in 'tzPOST'
$.ajax({
    url: 'php/ajax.php?action=' + action,
    data: data,
    dataType: 'json',

    // this is a anonymous callback function
    // it gets griggered whenever the request was successfull
    //
    // the $.ajax will pass the reponse to the anonymous functions first
    // parameter, witch internally is named 'r' now
    success: function(r) {
        // so 'r' is the webservers response
    }
});
```

So `r` is only a internal name, passed by the ajax request. You can easily rename `r`:

```
//                                                   | now the name is 'foo'
//                                                   |
$.tzPOST('submitChat', $(this).serialize(), function(foo) {
    params['id'] = foo.insertID;
});
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to explain it all step by step.

Comment: @Webeng, I added some more informations why `r` is named `r`. Hope this helps you.

Comment: Where is `tzPOST` defined?!

Comment: @EdwardBlack, read my answer, i wrote: `If you search for the tzPOST function in the scripts.js file` ...

Comment: Does someone know why he used `$.` before  `tzPOST`?

Comment: He registers the function `tzPOST` to jQuery by using `$`. The `$` of jQuery is an object, so `tzPOST` now is an parameter of the jQuery object, containing the function. If you would print `$` with `console.log($);` you will somewhere find the `tzPOST`.

Comment: Thank you for your time to explain this!

Answer (score 1):

As I have already commented, `r` is the response object.

#### tzPost code

```js
$.tzPOST = function(action, data, callback) {
  $.post('php/ajax.php?action=' + action, data, callback, 'json');
}
```

It internally calls `$.post` and if you see `$.post`

```js
$.post("ajax/test.html", function(data) {
  $(".result").html(data);
});
```

it returns response of the API call.

So in my understanding, he is calling `post` to save user and create a unique ID which is returned as a response of `.post` in `r` and is set to `params['id']`

#### Reference

- [$.post](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)

Comment: how does the program know that `r` is referring to the response object? The scheduled event handler didn't take any parameters: `$('#submitForm').submit(function(/*no parameters*/){`, so I assume there is something saying that `r` is the response object

Comment: As correctly said by @adrian Brand, its a parameter to a callback function. When you make a post call, its an async call and success handler is called once response is received. So to simplify, post will send something to server and wait for server to respond. Once response is received, it will call the callback function that you have provided and pass data to it.

Answer (score 1):

```
params['id'] = r.insertID;
```

is the same as

```
params.id = r.insertID;
```

r is the input parameter from the callback function of the post. It is the data that is sent back from the server.